# How to make plasma ball's lightning's moving more naturally?

Tags: animation-nodes

file link:[https://drive.google.com/open?id=10F5kQ2czSXHlGY3pEPQGOIJnO1IRcAGK](http://drive.google.com/open?id=10F5kQ2czSXHlGY3pEPQGOIJnO1IRcAGK)
I want to make the moving of lighting more naturally as red line showing, but i failed, could someone tell me how to do.

[image]

you can use the node to control line's segment that in the red rectangle as the picture showed.

[image]

blender version:2.79
animation node version:2.1

Thanks

Comment: So you want it to be smoother as shown in red?

Comment: Yes, but not only smoother, more like energy wave send from bottom to top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a smoother spline based on the wiggle node, you need to evaluate the noise at parameters of the spline. Moreover, to move the waves along the spline, simply add a scalar proportional to the frame number:

[image: Node Tree]